# Is it possible to filter for multiple strings in AG-Grid?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ag-grid

I have been using

```
myTable.api.setQuickFilter(string1);
```

with great success for a while, but I would like to be able to filter for string1, string2, or string3 at the same time and see all the results at once. Is this possible? I cannot find anything on the ag-grid docs.

Comment: I think you will need to use a custom filter. [This page](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-filtering/index.php) has an example of how to do it under "Custom Filter Example". If you look at the JS code, `PersonFilter` seems to do what you're looking for.

Comment: You are right, the answer is in the page. If I had the enterprise edition, I could make use of the "Custom Filter Example". Luckily the "External Filtering" section works too, just takes a little more work :) Make an answer out of your comment please.

Answer (score 1):

Since the custom filter example [here](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-filter-component/#example-custom-filter) focuses on individual column, using [External filter](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-filter-external/) seems to be the ideal solution.

You need to implement 2 methods - on `gridOptions`: `isExternalFilterPresent()` and `doesExternalFilterPass(node)`.

```
  isExternalFilterPresent() {
    return true; // to indicate external filtering is on
  }

  doesExternalFilterPass(node) {

// filter only if searchtext is there
   if (this.searchText) {
        return Object.values(node.data).includes(this.searchText.split(' ')[0]) // 'string1'
         || Object.values(node.data).includes(this.searchText.split(' ')[1]) // 'string2'
         || Object.values(node.data).includes(this.searchText.split(' ')[2]); // 'string3'
    }
   return true;
}

// assuming this is bound to your input field
  externalFilterChanged(newValue) {
    this.searchText = newValue;
    this.gridApi.onFilterChanged(); // letting the grid know filter has changed
  }
```

From docs -

> **isExternalFilterPresent**
>   is called exactly once every time the grid senses a filter change. It should return true if external filtering is active or false otherwise. If you return true,
>   `doesExternalFilterPass()` will be called while filtering, otherwise `doesExternalFilterPass()` will not be called.
>
> **doesExternalFilterPass**
>   is called once for each row node in the grid. If you return false, the node will be excluded from the final
>   set.
>
> If the external filter changes, you need to call `api.onFilterChanged()`
>   to tell the grid.

Comment: This was very helpful thanks. This is also the documentation on the external filter
https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/filter-external/